# How do I deploy an Azure Mobile Service to the staging environment?

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-roles

When I deploy an Azure Web Role using an Azure Cloud Service project I can deploy to staging:

[image: deployment screenshot]

Then I can switch quickly back-and-forth between staging and production in the Azure Portal:

[image: azure portal screenshot]

But when I deploy an Azure Mobile Service, or when I manage it in the Azure Portal, I cannot see how to deploy to the staging environment and then fast switch.

[image: mobile services deploy]

Is it possible to deploy an Azure Mobile Service to the staging environment and switch between staging and production? If it is, how?

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this with Mobile Service, but you may be able to do this with Traffic Manager.  Have you looked into that option?

Comment: Yeah, I just looked for that, and as of Jan 2015, not supported https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6430f748-cee5-4e08-b9ef-ee425b2ab369/will-microsoft-azure-traffic-manager-supporting-mobile-services-soon?forum=azuremobile  Still looking for you.

Comment: It doesn't appear there is an out of the box way to do this.  Maybe you could do it with a powershell script.  Let me know if you find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple deployments are not supported in Azure Mobile Service.One of the work around that I can think of is to create a new mobile service which can be replicated to serve as a staging mobile service and If everything seems to work fine you can publish the same deployment to the production mobile service.

I am also looking for better answers for the same.